# ASP.Net Redirect Request from a specific URL to a particular part of my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, redirect

Our Server Admin has setup a "Site Binding" in IIS for a website on the server, so that when an end user uses a specific url, it redirects to our site.

I need to be able to determine when one of these redirects has taken place, and then land the end user on a specific page on the website.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How many bindings are there? How many different URLs do you want to redirect to? i.e. do you require a static or dynamic solution.

Comment: There are 3 bindings, but i only need to act on thsi one particular binding, i think i need a re-write rule, i'm just not sure how.

Comment: Ok, don't think a web.config rewrite rule will suffice... try using the URLReferrer on the page the binding redirects to (and only that page) and if it matches the binding, redirect to where you want. Or as said below, use the server variables to detect the 'urlreferer' and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says that users are getting redirected to your site, but that's not really how IIS site bindings work. They are more like aliases for a single site. If that is the case, and the site has multiple bindings and you want to redirect based on which binding was used, then yes you would use a rewrite rule in web.config system.webServer section, like so:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="www.binding1.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.binding2.com/pages/binding1home" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the binding name in Request.ServerVariables under: "HTTP_HOST" or "SERVER_NAME". If you have access to the server variables? If so you could than redirect to a specific page if the specified binding name is found. (see: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the redirect is setup you could try and use the UrlReferrer property of the current request:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```